# Excel VBA and XML - clear table data

Tags: xml, vba, excel, excel-2010

I've created a spreadsheet with multiple worksheets, each containing XML mapped table elements from a number of different XML files.

I'm using VBA to refresh the data by pointing to a given file name in the current directory. However, if the file doesn't exist I want it to clear any existing data in the XML table.

If I delete the map the data remains and the link is lost.

Something like (and I don't know the correct syntax):

```
Sub ClearTables()
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim myTable As ListObject

For Each mySheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each myTable In mySheet.ListObjects
        'MsgBox myTable.Name
        myTable.DataBodyRange.Select
        ActiveCell.ClearContents
    Next myTable
Next mySheet
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could achieve this. I'd rather not have to parameterise and set the names of nearly 50+ tables when I want them all cleared at the begging of the macro.

All I keep getting is an error "Object variable or With block variable not set".

UPDATE: I've managed to fix this by testing for empty tables. The problem was due to some tables being empty already. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
Sub ClearTables()
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim myTable As ListObject

For Each mySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each myTable In mySheet.ListObjects
        'MsgBox myTable.Name
        'myTable.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
        If Not myTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            myTable.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
        End If
    Next myTable
Next mySheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
For Each mySheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each myTable In mySheet.ListObjects
        myTable.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    Next myTable
Next mySheet
```

Please note that the code does not test if the object is a table... actually I'm not sure what other `ListObject` - class objects you might have in the worksheets.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - for some reason it doesn't appear to work. It complains "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: That means the one of the things referenced don't exist. Is the workbook object in your Excel file really named `ThisWorkbook`? In anycase, A safer approach would be `Application.Workbooks("workbook_name")`, to be sure, because you might run the code fom another VBA project that does not have access to `ThisWorkbook` as object, so it needs to be retrieved somehow. :-)

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm lost on this one. I think everything is referenced correctly, I can't undestand why it doesn't work. The code I'm using has been included in my original post.

Comment: Okay, let's take it step by step: 1) Is `ClearTables` subroutine stored in the same project as the `Workbook`-class object `ThisWorkbook`? 2) Are there other objects embedded in the worksheets besides tables (e.g. charts)?

Comment: 1) The ClearTables sub is stored within a module of the XLSX spreadsheet. 2) No, just lots of tables. I used MsgBox to run through each object to check - only the tables I want clearing appear. The problem seems to be with myTable.DataBodyRange.ClearContents - it doesn't like it.

Comment: Woohoo! OK I seem to have fixed it - the problem was that one of the tables was empty, so it couldn't clear the contents without an error. I had to put a test in there to ignore empty tables. I'll post the code separately

Comment: @user3691037: Okay, I learned too something new today. Thanks. :-)